# Using the "value" attribute

Tags: html, forms, input, types

When dealing with different types of "input" tags, when is the "value" attribute used and what values it is suppose to received based on the type of "input"?

Comment: where are we using the value attribute? this is very language dependant ...

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I was talking about HTML. My bad for missing to specify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-value) :

> **The initial value of the control**. This attribute is optional except when the value of the type attribute is radio or checkbox.
>   When reloading the page, Firefox and IE will ignore the value specified in the HTML source, if the value was changed before the reload.

**For more details**, according to this [W3Schools documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp) :

The value attribute is used differently for different input types:

- For **button**, **reset**, and **submit** - it defines the **text** on the button
- For **text**, **password**, and **hidden** - it defines the **default value** of the input field
- For **checkbox**, **radio**, **image** - it defines the **value associated with the input** (this is also the value that is sent on submit)

Note: The value attribute **cannot be used with input** with the attribute **type="file"**.

Comment: I wouldn't reference w3schools - tis a minefield of bad practices and outdated code (it is getting better but for now stick to MDN)

Comment: MDN does not specify these informations about the value attribute. But sure, the best thing to do is to check on both (or more) sites and filter the informations you get

Comment: Of course this doc says that an input tag has a value attribute, but the informations in my answer does not appear in it (am I wrong ?)

Comment: yes - `The initial value of the control. This attribute is optional except when the value of the type attribute is radio or checkbox. When reloading the page, Firefox and IE will ignore the value specified in the HTML source, if the value was changed before the reload.` It's literally summed up in the first sentence

Comment: I don't think that it answers the original question, this is why I went on w3schools...
As I said in my first comment "MDN does not specify these informations about the value attribute", this doc doesn't help in this case

Comment: Personally I think it answers everything within the first sentence, OP asks about what the value attribute on the input element is used for. `the initial value of the control` - this is the case for all inputs ....

Comment: Haha ok :p So we are both right, we just understood the question differently, and I thought that OP wanted more info about it ! 
Please let me edit my answer and complete it with your reference

Comment: Personally, I prefer the source, either the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-input-value) or [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#a-form-control's-value)

Comment: @Rob tbf W3C would be (or at least should be) a very reliable valid source hahaha